# Track-mate unique bar-code reading

Tags: java, tags, issue-tracking, video-tracking

I have a program that I want to run on track-mate

Track-mate system identifies the object through the webcam which is connected to the PC. We place the webcam under the Plexiglas sheet (a transparent surface which is save for children) to track the bar-code and returns a digital feedback to the Track-mate...

the bar-code is saved in a database in a String format but our problem is that the bar-code readings are different each time we move the object on the surface, which makes it not unique for the exact object.
what can we do to solve this problem?

The program sources:

```
//LusidOSC a layer that reads tags from a webcam and send the result to any application 
    public LusidOSCJavaApp(){
            // create the client, on port 3333.
            lusidClient = new LusidClient(this, 3333);
            System.out.println("lusid osc java app ");
            System.out.println(View.getisRunning());
            while(View.getisRunning()){//SOME CODE TO DO}

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
        // these methods are called whenever a LusidOSC event occurs.


        // called when an object is added to the scene
        public void addLusidObject(LusidObject lObj) {
            System.out.println("add lusid object");

        //when object is added we add an instance of the object to lusidObj arraylist 
       lusidArr.add(lObj);

          //The problem is here because the ID isn't unique (but it should be unique...)
       if(lObj.getUniqueID().equals("0x111111AA1111"))  {
          System.out.println("you put the right shape");}
            else{
         System.out.println("error");}

         System.out.println("add object: "+lObj.getUniqueID());
         System.out.println("  location = 
         ("+lObj.getX()+","+lObj.getY()+","+lObj.getZ()+")");
           System.out.println("  rotation = 
        ("+lObj.getRotX()+","+lObj.getRotY()+","+lObj.getRotZ()+")");
           System.out.println("data = 
          ("+lObj.getEncoding()+","+lObj.getData()+")");
         System.out.println("#######################################");
         System.out.println(lusidArr.size());

        }

    // called when an object is removed from the scene
        public void removeLusidObject(LusidObject lObj) {
            lusidArr.remove(lObj);
            System.out.println("remove object: "+lObj.getUniqueID());
        }

        // called when an object is moved
        public void updateLusidObject (LusidObject lObj) {
            //System.out.println("update object: "+lObj.getUniqueID());

    ArrayList<LusidObject> currentLusidList = new ArrayList<LusidObject>
    (Arrays.asList(lusidClient.getLusidObjects()));
```

Download Link + source: [Trackmate](https://sourceforge.net/projects/trackmate/)

Comment: Do you have any code sample that you can share? How you do the scanning, how you convert the values, anything.

Comment: @MiklósTóth I've edited the question... Thanks,